# Convert between copper Ethernet and fiber optic

Tags: gigabit-ethernet, fiber

I have read:
[Unhappy with performance of gbit ethernet to fiber converter](https://superuser.com/questions/129820/unhappy-with-performance-of-gbit-ethernet-to-fiber-converter)

I want to convert fibre optics to Ethernet,will I get the same speed which I was getting with fibre optics after adding this:

[PTC-101 Series](http://www.moxa.com/product/PTC-101.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The industrial media converter should give 100 Mbps performance.  Do you need the Industrial PTC-101 or can you use something else? If this is a not rail-mount install, does the switch have a media fibre link available? Most Cisco, HP, D-Link, etc. switches will have a GBIC available that connects fible [GBIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_interface_converter)  With more info about your issue/question could have other ideas.

Comment: I can use anything to get the work done

Comment: Can you say what you are connecting the fibre to?  A network switch? Or?

Comment: to a network switch

Comment: Many switches will have a fibre adapter available eother as a GBIC or in a special slot.  What make model switch do you have?